# groovy / grails / unit testing / createCriteria.get

Tags: grails, groovy, mocking, hibernate-criteria

I can mock calls to:

```
MyDomainClass.createCriteria().list{
    eq('id',id)
    eq('anotherParameter',anotherParameterId)
}
```

with:

```
def myCriteria = [
    list : {Closure  cls -> returnThisObject}
]
MyDomainClass.metaClass.static.createCriteria = { myCriteria }
```

as advised at:

http://davistechyinfo.blogspot.com/2010/01/mocking-hibernate-criteria-in-grails.html

but for:

```
MyDomainClass.createCriteria().get{
    eq('id',id)
    eq('anotherParameter',anotherParameterId)
}
```

This approach fails - maybe because 'get' is a keyword in a way 'list' is not. Can anyone advise - being able to mock this in domain classes should be possible, without simply abandoning unit test coverage for methods that use `createCriteria().get{}`.

Suggestions much appreciated,

Alex

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've found a solution that doesn't compromise my ability to write unit tests -

```
def myCriteria = new Expando();
myCriteria .get = {Closure  cls -> returnThisObject}         
MyDomainClass.metaClass.static.createCriteria = {myCriteria }
```

which does exactly what I wanted and potentially supports testing supplied arguments. Thanks for the other response. Hope this is useful to others testing domain/createCriteria() methods.

Comment: Do you know how to mock the list but the get keep the actual implementation of the code?

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't bother. Instead create methods in your domain class and mock those. This makes testing easier but more importantly has the advantage of keeping persistence where it belongs instead of scattering it throughout the code base:

```
class MyDomainClass {
   String foo
   int bar

   static MyDomainClass findAllByIdAndAnotherParameter(long id, long anotherParameterId) {
      createCriteria().list {
         eq('id',id)
         eq('anotherParameter',anotherParameterId)
      }
   }

   static MyDomainClass getByIdAndAnotherParameter(long id, long anotherParameterId) {
      createCriteria().get {
         eq('id',id)
         eq('anotherParameter',anotherParameterId)
      }
   }
}
```

Then in your tests, just mock it as

```
def testInstances = [...]
MyDomainClass.metaClass.static.findAllByIdAndAnotherParameter = { long id, long id2 ->
   return testInstances
}
```

and

```
def testInstance = new MyDomainClass(...)
MyDomainClass.metaClass.static.getByIdAndAnotherParameter = { long id, long id2 ->
   return testInstance
}
```

Comment: I've simplified this to the following:

Comment: String hello = "hello"

def map = [get1:{Closure  cls -> hello}, address:"somewhere"]

print map.get1{}

Comment: String hello = "hello"

def map = [get:{Closure  cls -> hello}, address:"somewhere"]

print map.get{}

Comment: The difference is that when the map key is 'get1' then printing map.get1{} prints "hello", but when the key is 'get' then null is returned. Maybe 'get' is a language conflict so i need an entirely different approach for mocking out createCriteria().get{}.

Comment: this is a better and cleaner solution than the first one as domain classes should only know about there internals not the clients

Answer (score 2):

This should be much simpler now with the `GrailsUnitTestCase.mockDomain`[1](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#9.1%20Unit%20Testing) method.

#### grails-app/domain/sandbox/grails/foo/Something.groovy

```
package sandbox.grails.foo

class Something {
    String name
}
```

#### test/unit/sandbox/grails/foo/SomethingTests.groovy

```
package sandbox.grails.foo

import grails.test.mixin.*
import org.junit.*

@TestFor(Something)
class SomethingTests {

    void testSomething() {

        mockDomain(Something, [
            new Something(name: 'Foo'),
            new Something(name: 'Bar'),
            new Something(name: 'Boo'),
            new Something(name: 'Baz')
        ])

        def actuals = Something.createCriteria().list(sort: 'name', order: 'asc') {
            like('name', '%oo')
        }

        assertEquals 2, actuals.size()

    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely from **Grails 2.0** onwards, but I do recall using it in **1.8.x** as well.