# How to mock createCriteria() in grails 2.1.1?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

I am working on Unit Tests for a groovy n grails application v-2.1.1

I have a `createCriteria()` to mock, which looks like below controller code snippet:

```
  def updateList = {
    def Cr = Book.createCriteria()

    def Find = Cr.list() {
      and {
        eq ("name", params.name)
        eq ("age", params.age)
        eq ("prop", params.prop) 
      }
    }
  }
```

My test method looks like:

```
void testUpdateList(){
  try{
    controller.request.method = 'POST'
    controller.session.userName = "amy"
    controller.params.name = "A1"
    controller.params.age = "four"
    controller.params.prop = "D1"
    controller.updateList()     
  }catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace()
  }
}
```

I am able to pass `params` to the controller method through my test method.
Can you please help me in mocking `createCriteria()` whith an example of Mocking the data so that I can validate it?

Thanks in advance
amy

Answer (score 0):

I think the code snippets in this question:
[groovy / grails / unit testing / createCriteria.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720656/groovy-grails-unit-testing-createcriteria-get)

will show you what you need to do, roughly